# Select from table with composite primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have an injection table called `StudentSchool` that contains :

```
StudentSchoolID  StudentId   SchoolID
1                233         22
```

But now I want to make the table with composite primary key like this:

```
StudentId   SchoolID
    233         22
```

In the first case I select using

```
select * from StudentSchool  
where (StudentId = 233) and (SchoolID = 22)
```

but in the second case how to do that with it as it is a primary key

Comment: Your query stays the same - whether or not the primary key is a composite key has no impact on your query.

Comment: so what is different between adding my StudentSchoolID and remove it and add composite one it was easy in asp.net to add a data key name as StudentSchoolID but now adding the both Id's is not validating my business

Comment: Well - ASP.NET is a different story! You didn't make **any** mention of ASP.NET in your post..... on the SQL Server side, having a composite index has no impact on your query. ASP.NET is a different story....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly.
If you want the student with StudentId 233 and SchoolId 22, then it's the same query like for the first case.

Comment: so what is different between adding my StudentSchoolID  and remove it and add composite one it was easy in asp.net to add a data key name as StudentSchoolID  but now adding the both Id's is not validating my business

Comment: Technically there is a difference between using a surrogate key like your StudentSchoolId and using a composite key (and there are lots of religious wars going on because of that!). But for your query, there is no difference. It's the same for both cases.

Comment: yes the problem between me and my manager is he want me to remove it and set a composite one i told him tell me one difference he did not tell my some thing that can convince me  that is why i am asking this question there is a war here right now :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am missing something but your query would be the same

```
select * from YourNewTable  where (StudentId  =233)and (ScoohlID=22)
```

Answer (score 1):

If by "adding the both Id's is not validating my business" means that you get a PK violation when you try to create the composite key, then its because you have more than one row with the same `StudentId` + `SchoolID` pair.

If this is the case, then you need to make some clean up on that table, by removing the duplicated rows before creating the composite PK.

To find out the duplicated pairs, you can do something like

```
select StudentId, SchoolID
  from StudentSchool
 group by StudentId, SchoolID
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: no there is no duplication because the student is only assigned to one school and i have revised it there is no duplication  thanks a lot for your reply it answered another question now :)

Answer (score 1):

If understand right, that StudentSchoolID in that first case is the primary key of a join table, is it?

Maybe your difference is in the first case where the best query would be:

```
select * from StudentSchool  
where StudentSchoolID = 1
```

and StudentSchoolID is intended as the representative of "StudentID" and "SchoolID" pair.

Your query is the case for the second where main ID is not present.

About what way to use...well I don't know. Personally I prefer the second, but I think too that it often depends (who knew!) on the specific case.